# Make a data binding between 2 properties in different classes

Tags: c#, .net, class, data-binding

I have to classes in C# every one contain one proptery so i want to make a data binding between the proprty in the first class and the property in the other one how can i do it. There is an example:

```
 public class FirstClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public void BindNameFromRealName()
    {
        // what can i write here ?
    }
}

public class Origine
{
    public string RealName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a way to feed the Origine class into the FirstClass. Perhaps a required property for Origine in FirstClass? You can't magically make it know there are other objects in play.

Answer (score 0):

I echo the previous post. Perhaps you want to evaluate your need; what exactly is it you're trying to do. Why do you want to carry data using 2 objects instead of one? If this is like Data Transfer Object <-> Business Object data transfer in scenarios like web service calls, then you might want to check object mapping frameworks like [Automapper](http://automapper.org/)

Comment: this should rather be a comment than a answer.

Comment: i wan't to map between types but properties !

Comment: There's no type to type mapping per se. Automapper for example, has to do reflection to discover properties. It's convention-based and it infers like when properties with same names are mapped to each other. If it cannot infer, then you have to map it manually. It spares you from all the mis-mapping that could introduce subtle bugs.